# webpack bundle.js not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use webpack dev server, but can't access my `bundle.js` file.

Edit: I am using [this webpack config](http://andrejgajdos.com/setting-up-webpack-for-es6-react-sass-and-bootstrap/) without *bower-webpack-plugin*.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_modules",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "history": "^1.13.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "json-markup": "^0.1.6",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0-rc4",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.11",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js', 
        sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {   
              test: /\.js[x]?$/, 
              loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
              exclude: /node_modules/ 
            },
            {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap' ]
            },
              {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap' ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [ 'style', 'css']
              },
              { test: /\.woff$/,   loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
              { test: /\.woff2$/,   loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2" },
              { test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BowerWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <!-- include the webpack-dev-server script so our scripts get reloaded when we make a change -->
    <!-- we'll run the webpack dev server on port 8090, so make sure it is correct -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <!-- include the bundle that contains all our scripts, produced by webpack -->
    <!-- the bundle is served by the webpack-dev-server, so serve it also from localhost:8090 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**console output**

```
and:react_modules and$ npm run start

> react_modules@1.0.0 start /Users/and/devel/react_modules
> npm run serve | npm run dev


> react_modules@1.0.0 dev /Users/and/devel/react_modules
> webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090

  0% compilehttp://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from http://localhost:8090/assets
content is served from /Users/and/devel/react_modules
Hash: dd2f28f3fef16a34048b  
Version: webpack 1.12.2
Time: 612ms

ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/and/devel/react_modules/src/index.jsx: Unexpected token (5:2)
  3 | 
  4 | ReactDOM.render(
> 5 |   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    |   ^
  6 |   document.getElementById('content')
  7 | );
  8 | 
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:507:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:260:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:240:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:171:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:153:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:120:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:966:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (/Users/and/devel/react_modules/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:336:20)
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

When I run dev server, I get 404 Not Found `http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your `package.json` you are using the new [babel 6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) release. However you don't have all the required dependencies for this new release. According to [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#installation) you need to install `babel-preset-es2015` too:

> `npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

As you are also using React, you need the react preset to be installed too. So install both:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Create a file in your package folder called `.babelrc` to keep the [babel configuration](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/) and enable both presets:

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

And then run the server again:

```
npm run dev
```

Then http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js should show the bundled module.

My diagnosis:

You cannot get the the `bundle.js` because your `npm run dev` throws some errors trying to apply the babel loader because it is not properly configured. Then, when you try to request the `bundle.js` file you get a 404 error because **it has not been generated**.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I installed babel-preset-es2015, but it didn't help (bundle.js is still not found). Please see my edited package.json

Comment: @Matt Check the updated answer. With new Babel 6 you need to set up your presets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem mostly with pointing bundle js in index.html. The reason webpack bundle.js not found because you need to specify absolute path in index.html. Say suppose your bundle.js and index.html is generated under dist folder then it should be something like below

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the home page In `.env` file

```
PUBLIC_URL=https://example.com
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to change your script path in index.html file to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Btw in console is message `webpack result is served from http://localhost:8090/assets`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not bundle.js it's bundle**d**.js  at least this is what fixed it for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundled.js"></script>
```