# localhost node server can't load bundle.js from webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm learning react following [Isomorphic App tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.byjo66oz7).

Since i'm really new to react, I strictly followed the tutorial, writing every single script as described. When I launch the server with `npm start`, the browser on `localhost:3000` doesn't render the page as expected, showing only the title without the input field and the button for adding a new todo. Opening the Dev Console, comes out that `bundle.js` can't get loaded and i really can't understand why.

If I point the browser to `localhost:3000/home`, on the other hand, it renders the input field and the button, but again `bundle.js` is not loaded, and the "app" doesn't work (i.e. doesn't add a new todo).

i'm new to react, webpack and node, i googled a lot but i really can't get it through, i don't know what's happening. `package.json` and `webpack.config` too have been created following the tutorial indications.

I'm banging my head against the wall since a few days, please ease my pain, i beg you :D

here's my config:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "isomorphic-redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": "https://github.com/bananaoomarang/isomorphic-redux",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./shared node --harmony .",
    "dev": "npm run start & webpack-dev-server --progress --color",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --color -p --config webpack.prod.config.js"
  },
  "author": "Milo Mordaunt <milomord@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.7.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "history": "^1.9.1",
    "immutable": "^3.7.5",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "1.0.0-rc3",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "latest",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "eslint": "^1.4.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.3.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config`

```
var path    = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry:  [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './client'
  ],
  output: {
    path:     path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'shared'],
    extensions:         ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:    /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '*': 'http://127.0.0.1:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000)
    },
    host: '127.0.0.1'
  }
};
```

the project structure is the following:

```
client/
---index.jsx
shared/
---actions/
---components/
------...
------Home.jsx
------index.jsx
---reducers/
---routes.jsx

index.js
server.jsx
package.json
webpack.config
.babelrc
```

Comment: what does your output `dist` look like?

Comment: @JoshBeam i don't have a `dist`, i think. Or am I completely wrong? It should be all loaded from memory (like, in theory, `bundle.js`), right?

Comment: It's outputting your bundle into `dist/bundle.js` according to your webpack config (this will happen in memory unless you just run `webpack` and not the dev server).

Comment: @JoshBeam `dist` has only `bundle.js`. File it's huge, [here it is](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80P5wPtzz3Od0dUZ3VfS3RSajg)

Comment: Maybe try changing the script in your index document to point to `dist/bundle.js`

Comment: @JoshBeam still not working :( [GET answers 404](http://i.imgur.com/49Vmzsk.png)

Comment: this could help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502987/webpack-bundle-js-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `package.json` you are using the new babel 6 release. However you don't have all the required dependencies for this new release. According to babel-loader you need to install `babel-preset-es2015` too:

`npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

As you are also using React, you need the react preset to be installed too. So install both:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`

Create a file in your package folder called `.babelrc` to keep the babel configuration and enable both presets:

```
.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

And then run the server again:

`npm run dev`

Then `http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js` should show the bundled module.

My diagnosis:

You cannot get the the `bundle.js` because your `npm run dev` throws some errors trying to apply the babel loader because it is not properly configured. Then, when you try to request the `bundle.js` file you get a 404 error because it has not been generated.

From -> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502987/webpack-bundle-js-not-found`

Answer (score 3):

You are running two somehow different setups that don't know of each other immediately. When you do `npm start` you fire up the node process with your `index.js` file that in the end serves some html referencing a non-existing bundle.js file.

On the other hand, when you run the `webpack-dev-server`, all bundled content will reside only in-memory and will never be written to your disk. so the file will not be available to the server started with `npm start`.

But as you can see in the webpack config, it contains a section where a `proxy` is configured to route all unknown paths to a backend on port 3000. This is where the two setups are connected. You need to run the webpack-dev-server using `npm run dev` and then open `localhost:8080` in your browser. This task automatically runs `npm start` as first command (which runs your node app) and afterwards starts the `webpack-dev-server`. So if you want to access your application, you must not use port `3000` but either go to `8080` which is the port of the `webpack-dev-server`.

The error you get is also documented in the blog post at this position: https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#4c7c

> If you see a errors in the console about bundle.js not being found, Don’t Panic. This is because the client is trying to load bundle.js, but we haven’t configured Webpack’s entry point yet, so we get nothing.

And the solution can be found some lines later (https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#0eed):

> Now we can start our app with npm run dev (instead of npm start) and Webpack will serve our client a bundle.js, so it can do it’s own routing from here-on-out. It still won’t look very interesting, but visiting http://localhost:8080/ should work without errors.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed this warning in the tutorial, but it still doesn't work. Running `npm run dev` and pointing the browser to `localhost:8080` don't even render html but the [directory contents](http://i.imgur.com/Wx1YlbK.png). Ireally don't understand what i'm doin' wrong. And why there's the need of this proxy config? I mean, why not running just one setup (dev server or something), instead?